# 'Click/tap' or 'click or tap'

Tags: punctuation, slash

I'm writing documentation for an online system, with sentences like this:

> Click/tap the ‘cog’ icon of a content filter to edit it.

This does not go down well with Microsoft Word. The grammar checker advises me: 'Consider revising'.

However, when I change it to:

> Click **or** tap the ‘cog’ icon of a content filter to edit it.

... all is well. Which makes me wonder: is it bad to use a slash here? Is there perhaps a formal rule about this?

Comment: I'd say there's no "formal rule" but it's plain bad to ever use slashes. Note too that you're better to simply say only one word or the other. They mean the same thing.

Comment: @JoeBlow For many people, they do not mean the same thing (even if they *do* the same thing). A *click* generally refers to the press of a button on a mouse (or equivalent). A *tap* generally refers to a direct touch on a touch sensitive screen. Also, there are times when a slash is useful, such as to save space, or to indicate an identity between things with alternative. names.

Comment: Use @media handheld, only screen and hide the Click when mobile without keyboard and hide Tap when not

Comment: Hey bib - I'm pretty sure he's referring to an on-screen experience.  (either using a mouse, or, touchscreen.) In a word, to further address the excellent points you raise, the OP should **explain exactly the milieu in question**

Comment: @mplungjan I was not looking for a technical solution.

Comment: I however provided one anyway

Comment: @JoeBlow 'Online system'... What 'milieus' could that be?

Comment: kasimir - I have no idea. (My refrigerator is online.) Can the users use **touch screen devices**.  Can the users use **desktop computers** (with a mouse).  In short is it **both** touch/mouse devices - or just one or the other?  Are there any other devices/interfaces we should know about?

Comment: It is both touch/mouse. No other interfaces to consider. However, I was mostly curious about the slash thing, not whether I should use 'click' instead of 'click/tap'. Come to think if it, users with laptops 'tap' as well (using a touchpad). This makes any 'technical' solution (showing either 'click' or 'tap') impossible, since you cannot see or detect the user's input device.

Comment: You can describe "clicking" a virtual button as "clicking" - no problem there.  (You can use every word, which can be used on a physical button, on a virtual button.  For example "up" etc.)  Regarding -- **if you do use two words** -- whether you should use an or or a slash.  Use the or.  I offer some reasoning in the long answer, cheers

Comment: Use *choose* or *select* or some such. How the user physically makes the cog choice should not be part of the description. Describing the interaction at that level of detail is generally not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For the record:

Your specific question **"is it bad to use a slash here?"**, in my opinion it is bad to use a slash **in your specific example**, for this reason:

*Note that you can in fact perfectly replace the slash with a " or ", in this case.*

In my opinion, if that sentence in italics is true, you should do it.

Note that in other situations you **can not** replace a slash with an " or "; IMO it is then good and proper to use a slash.

Your specific question **"Is there perhaps a formal rule about this?"**  There **is no** such formal rule.  In different "specific style books" they may have a rule. (For example, ScientificAmerican magazine writers may have some specific house rule.)

In my opinion, the logical and good rule to apply is *if you can in fact perfectly replace the slash with a " or ", then choose the " or ".* But that is just a formulation I have come up with, applying all the broad general thinking on slashes and " or "s. i hope it helps!

---

**Note** In my opinion **regarding your specific sentence**.  (This is -extra of your literal question: a long-standing tradition here on ELU!) I believe the best thing to write is simply "click" because that applies perfectly whether there is actually a physical click (eg with a mouse) or when describing a button on a touchscreen. My reasoning for using one word rather than two **(regardless of slash/or issues)**: you are always always better to "K.I.S.S." in writing. if you can cover all relevant situations with one word, do that.

---

**An important point which has arisen**: note that regarding virtual controls on screens. We use the entire gamut of words which could refer to real physical controls, on, virtual controls. (So, words like turn, throw, slide, in, out, positions, clickstops, springs, click, push, etc etc etc.) This is normal and utterly established.

**Just another minor point"** note that the virtual controls on PC/Mac screens, are indeed, just as virtual as the virtual controls on toushscreen devices. It's true that a mouse has a "real" click, but when you say "click **such and such button** on the screen" you're talking about the virtual button, not the mouse. (Note too that within a short time, all screens everywhere will also include a 30 cent touch layer, so there will be no distinction between with-mouse devices.)

Comment: So are you saying/implying that people/writers/twits who use/employ/write slashes/solidi/virgulae are being lazy/sloppy/uncaring/stupid? Because if you aren’t, I certainly am. :)

Comment: I’m teasing you. Omnipresent slashes run a close second behind ubiquitous ellipses for peskily pervasive peeve-points. People can’t decide whether to use one or the other or both, and if both, whether to use *and* or *or*, so they push their own sloppy thinking on the rest of us, spreading their own general confusion like a meme virus.

Comment: Quite.  However for me the ultimate is apostrophe misuse.  Pls see frame six!! http://achewood.com/index.php?date=09122008

Comment: This is a proper answer, perhaps opinions differ though. Interesting point: does 'click' refer to the user action in a mechanical way (a mouse producing a 'click' noise) or a figurative way (making a button 'click')?

Comment: The Apo’strophic Jihad has been duly appri’sed of th’is dis’order. ‘Be s’eeing you!’

Comment: On a desktop system with a mouse, clicking could refer to literally clicking the mouse {note that may have nothing to do with virtual buttons onscreen} or it may refer to "clicking" a onscreen button.  Buttons on desktop-screens and on iPads are "equally virtual".  Note that in all cases we use all words from the physical world, for controls, when referring to virtual controls.

Comment: (I just saw an iPad scratch app with a "virtual mouse" that you " ' clicked ' " and it then "clicked" a virtual button on a .. believe it .. virtual screen! heheh)

Comment: Also, in terms of clarity, tablet users will know what to do when a button says 'Click here!' And Microsoft seems to agree on the slash thing. So, I'm inclined to change 'click/tap' to just 'click'.

Comment: a good point, "click here" is what you see

Comment: How about 'hover' vs. 'tap'? You can not (always) 'hover' on a tablet. Tablet users have to tap the right spot to achieve the same effect as a mouse 'hover'. Would you therefore say 'hover over or tap on'?

Comment: Another thing, considering the 'virtual approach': would you say 'click on a button' or 'click a button'? To me, the first implies a mechanical action.

Comment: I would say **"Click the 'cog' to choose a filter"** I would not say on or a, and I would not say 'icon' since it is redundant.  if you like icon or button, say **"Click the 'cog' icon to choose a filter"** or **"Click the 'cog' button to choose a filter"**  In short don't say "on" or "on a"

Comment: hint, I've gotta get an upvote here on this answer soon ;-)